# Google Chrome On Startup Option Disabled

Tags: google-chrome

following an update of my LENOVO T14s laptop, Chrome starts on the setting page and I can't change it back to other options. I tried looking and it says I need to delete a registry key or something, but all the paths provided to get to that are not correct for me.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened due to this (the on startup options is on main page of settings menu you just need to scroll down)

[image: Settings Image Chrome], check if same is the issue for you, click on the 3 dots next to the link and change the link.

If not you will be better of uninstalling and reinstalling chrome from scratch rather then messing with registry (if you have synced your google account with chrome no settings, bookmarks or password will be lost after reinstalling, you will only need to log in)